# Practicality of generating electricity from ambient noise

Tags: low-power, generator

My living space has constant supply of a variety of annoying sounds thanks to a lack of proper sound deadening. I was wondering what is the practicality of creating an energy "leech" array using microphones? my current circuit that I am thinking of is using a lav-mic, slapping a full bridge rectifier across the output. That feeds into a small ceramic capacitor for some semblance of smoothing. Five of the previously mentioned would be wired in series and feed into a 5v supercap and then a joule thief will step up the voltage to 5v and will be fed into a li-ion battery management (charge/discharge circuit like the ones found in battery banks). I was thinking if there is such annoying noises might as well put them to use.

TL;DR: Is it feasible to create a low-power generator from microphones to harvest power from annoying noise sources?

Comment: Well, surely you can convert air oscillations into electricity. But I doubt it will be enough to power like anything.

Comment: Your microphone will hardly forward bias a diode and the diode will absorb most of the energy. Look up energy harvesting techniques instead. Typically you need significant levels of vibration to cause a significant mass to vibrate.

Comment: TL/DR : Not worth it.

Comment: There is not much power in this noise. I would imagine some sort of optimized speaker that could be useful- membrane, magnet on a weak spring, a coil. The whole thing must be mass-produced and used as a filler in walls. I don't know, seems much more complicated and expensive than just proper isolation.

Comment: would a bigger microphone help with overcoming the diode? my noise sources can vary from the level equivalent to clacking of boots but constant, and in some extreme cases a straight up 2-stroke engine from the neighbor. I'm fairly confident that there is plenty of power from the noise to be had.

Comment: I don't plan on using it as deadening. I simply want to see what kind of power I might generate. If it isn't useable, so be it.

Comment: Consider that you have to use an amplifier to raise the microphone signal to a useful level just to record it.  Microphone signals are **weak.**

Comment: A large speaker will pick up lower frequencies and output a low-impedance signal. A transformer can step this up to a voltage you could work with.

Comment: @hacktastical suggests a valid approach. Michael Rainey built a voice-powered radio transmitter that could generate 20mW power output. However, the audio coupling to the loudspeaker was very tight. This would not work for ambient noise without a large acoustic-horn to couple weak audio efficiently. http://qrp.gr/technology/voicepassivecw/MJRainey%20-%20New%20England%20Code%20Talker.htm

Comment: such kind of power harvesting would use a piezo transducer probably. Depending on the kind of noise you *could* optimize the horn for the relevant frequency. Also depends on how much noise and how much power you need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about some numbers?

- 0.775 volts into 600 ohms is one milliwatt.
- A blue LED needs 3 volts and 20 milliamperes.  That's 60 milliwatts.
- If you collect energy at 1 milliwatt for 60 seconds then you will have enough energy to light that blue LED for one second.
- Typical microphone output levels are about 1/1000 of one milliwatt.
- It would take about 60000 seconds (nearly 17 hours) to collect enough energy to light the LED for one second.

Keep in mind that all of those numbers are **optimistic** estimates and that they assume that you can store all collected energy without losses and that you can convert voltages without loss.

There is no way that you can collect a useful amount of energy with a normal microphone in a normal home.